# Que es lo que toma o como lo toma,de la base de datos " Article.objects.all() "?

Tags: django, django-models

Buenas estoy practicando con django como parte de un curso de python, y en un ejercicio de una web ,hacemos una vista o "views" que es la siguiente:

**Con esta vista o funcion,podemos listar en el html todo el contenido de una base de datos**

```
def articulos(request): # con esta funcion podemos mostrar en una template todos los objetos de una lista
    
    articulos = Article.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'articulos.html',{
        'articulos':articulos
    })
```

**Y esto es la clase o modelo article**

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    content = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(default='null')
    public = models.BooleanField()
    created_at= models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at= models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Mi pregunta es como funciona lo siguiente:

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}
{% block title %} Pagina de Pruebas{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
<h1 class="title">Lista de articulos</h1>
    <ul>
        {% for articulo in articulos %}
        <li>
            <h4>{{articulo.id}} . {{articulo.title}}</h4>
            <span>{{articulo.created_at}}</span>
            <p>
                {{articulo.content}}
                <br>
                <a href="{% url 'borrar' id=articulo.id %}">Eliminar</a>
            </p>
            
            <br>
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>


{% endblock content %}
```

**En teoria aqui utilizamos for para iterar y que recorra articulo**
De esta manera,me muestra el contenido en la web,en este caso lo que le pedi que es **articulo.title** e **articulo.id**.

Pero si no utilizo for y saco el objeto directamente haciendo por ejemplo **'articulo'** , o **'articulo.id'**,en la primera me sale esto
"<QuerySet [<Article: Article object (1)>, <Article: Article object (5)>, <Article: Article object (6)>, <Article: Article object (7)>]>"

y en la segunda simplemente no muestra nada, **Entonces mi pregunta es ,¿que es articulo ,y for que hace en esta situacion,por que for puede sacar su contenido y de forma normal no puedo?**

Seguro es algo basico que estoy pasando por alto,pero desde ya si alguien tiene la paciencia para responderme gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes hacerlo asi:

https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

primero instalamos debug toolbar:

```
python -m pip install django-debug-toolbar
```

abrimos el setting.py

```
## agregamos a INSTALLED_APPS
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # ...
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "debug_toolbar",
    # ...
]

## TEMPLATES 
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        # ...
    }
]

INTERNAL_IPS = [
    # ...
    "127.0.0.1",
    # ...
]

STATIC_URL = "static/"
```

ahora en urls.py

```
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    path('__debug__/', include('debug_toolbar.urls')),
]
```

ahora solo con correr runserver

podriamos ver esto en todas nuestras paginas en una esquina:

[image: debug toolbar]

Comment: Ohhh se ve muy util,muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

`articulo` es una variable usada dentro de tu `ciclo for()` para poder extraer a cada uno de los elementos dentro de tu lista de artículos obtenidos en la función `articulos(request)`.

El for dentro de la plantilla se encarga de imprimir en pantalla los atributos `id`, `title` y `created_at` de cada uno de los articulos guardados en tu modelo `Article()`.

Si quieres conocer un poco más de las etiquetas que usas dentro de tus plantillas de Django te recomiendo darle un vistazo a esta pagina [Built-in template tags and filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/)

Comment: Si si entiendo gracias,soy nuevo y me cuesta un poco todo esto